# Fun PDEs and exact solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am building an PDE solver and would like some PDEs to test it on. However to test it works I want to compare it to exact solutions but I'm not having much luck finding these online. I currently have

- diffusion equation with time-varying boundaries
- wave equation with constant boundaries

however I would like to also test

- diffusion equation with no-flux boundaries
- advection-diffusion equation with mixed boundaries
- advection-diffusion equation with constant boundaries
- kvd equation with any boundaries
- benjamin-bona-manhony equation with any boundaries

however I am having trouble finding suitable initial conditions and an exact solutions to these. Any suggestions of initial conditions/boundary conditions/exact solutions would be very much appreciated. If you have any exciting equations you like I would also love to hear!

Comment: Probably one of the most classic PDE is the heat equation$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha \nabla^2u$$( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation ) another, more simple, is the undamped one dimension wave-equation, vibrations of an elastic string$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: [Polyanin - Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations for Engineers and Scientists](https://www.amazon.it/Differential-Equations-Engineers-Scientists-2016-01-15/dp/B01FIXHLX2/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1520456258&sr=8-3&keywords=polyanin)

Comment: Try: https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/pde_in_cas.htm

Comment: Search for PDE: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html